# Java Vowel Counter Alternative Method

Tags: java, loops

I'm writing a simple vowel-counter and was wondering if there's a cleaner alternative (possibly a loop?) to replace all of the `else if`'s when comparing `s` to the various vowels.

I can't think of a simple way to do this effectively as the number of each vowel must be shown individually.  It would be very simple if it was just a total vowel count.

I'm quite new to Java so I don't know what can be used to clean this up.  If this is the best option, then I am contempt -- but I love cleaning up code where it can be!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int A = 0, E = 0, I = 0, O = 0, U = 0;

    System.out.print("Type a single word > ");
    String word = input.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
      String s = word.substring(i, i + 1);

      if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) { A++; } 
      else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) { E++; }
      else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("I")) { I++; }
      else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("O")) { O++; }
      else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("U")) { U++; } 
    }

    int total = A + E + I + O + U;
    System.out.println("\n'" + word + "' has...\n" + A + " A's\n" + E + " E's\n" + I + " I's\n" + O + " O's\n" + U + " U's\nTotal vowels: " + total + "\n");

    input.close();
  }
}
```

Input:

```
Coding
```

Output:

```
'Coding' has...
0 A's
0 E's
1 I's
1 O's
0 U's
Total vowels: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a less repetitive way to code it, using an int array for the counts, and a string holding the sequence of vowels.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type a single word > ");
        String word = input.next();
        String vowels = "AEIOU";
        int[] counts = new int[vowels.length()];
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            int index = vowels.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(i)));
            if (index >= 0) {
                ++counts[index];
                ++total;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%n'%s' has...%n", word);
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; ++i) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s's%n", counts[i], vowels.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.printf("Total vowels: %s%n", total);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Type a single word > Coding

'Coding' has...
0 A's
0 E's
1 I's
1 O's
0 U's
Total vowels: 2
```

Comment: Ah, good ol' arrays.  Thanks for this!  I also like how you formatted the output.  Very neat.  Unfortunately we aren't meant to use `charAt`, but it's nice to see alternate ways of doing the same thing!

Comment: You can use a char array instead of a string if you're not allowed to use `charAt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid a lot of repetition by using a `Map` that associates vowels (keys) to their frequencies within the `word` passed at runtime (values).

It is worth noting that a `LinkedHashMap` is used in the below example as to preserve the insertion order of keys for printing at the end of the program - as would not be the case with a `HashMap`.

```java
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // Define Map to map vowels to frequencies
        Map<Character, Integer> vowels = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
        vowels.put('A', 0);
        vowels.put('E', 0);
        vowels.put('I', 0);
        vowels.put('O', 0);
        vowels.put('U', 0);
        
        // Get input from user
        System.out.print("Type a single word > ");
        String word = input.next();
        
        // Iterate across word 
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
          String c = word.substring(i, i+1); // Get current char
          for (Character key : vowels.keySet()) { // Iterate across vowels
              if (c.equalsIgnoreCase(key.toString()))  { 
                  vowels.put(key, vowels.get(key)+1); // Increment vowel frequency if matched
                  break; // Break inner loop and move to next char in word
          }
        }
        // Sum total
        int total = 0;
        for (Character key : vowels.keySet()) {
        total += vowels.get(key);
        }
        
        // Print results to console
        System.out.println("\'" + word + "\'" + " has...");
        for (Character key : vowels.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(vowels.get(key) + " " + key + "\'s");
        }
        System.out.println("Total vowels: " + total);
        
        input.close();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like more effort than it's worth.  What are the benefits of using a `Map`?

Comment: To be fair the example I provided is quite verbose. Simply trying to give you some options instead of bif `if`/`else` trees. It may be overkill for this specific problem as you are only printing the results and not processing them further, however thought it worth bringing up as associative arrays (such as Java `Map` derived classes) are quite often a solid choice when seeking to map keys to values (as you are doing here with vowels and their frequencies within the text) and one used here solves your `if`/`else` tree issue.

Comment: Oh, okay - I see how that could come in useful in other applications.  Thanks!